# Terraform ignore sub-block changes in AWS metric_query

Tags: terraform, amazon-ebs

Am in the process of trying to configure IOPS alerting on EBS volumes as we move them to GP3.  The plan is to configure the alarms in TF but to shift the setting of the target to a lambda that can keep the alarm up-to-date based on lifecycle changes to the ASG.  For GP2 volumes I was able to get this configured cleanly and have `ignore_changes` on the `dimensions` block of each alert but now that I have moved to several `metric_query` blocks I cannot seem to find a way to address the nested `dimension` config.

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "foobar" {
  count               = length(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names)
  alarm_name          = "${local.env_short}_app_volume_IOPS_${data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[count.index]}"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = "5"
  threshold                 = "2700"
  alarm_description         = "IOPS in breach of 90% of provisioned"
  insufficient_data_actions = []
  actions_enabled     = "true"
  datapoints_to_alarm = "5"
  alarm_actions       = [aws_sns_topic.app_alert.arn]
  ok_actions          = [aws_sns_topic.app_alert.arn]
  metric_query {
    id          = "e1"
    expression  = "(m1+m2)/PERIOD(m1)"
    label       = "IOPSCalc"
    return_data = "true"
  }

  metric_query {
    id = "m1"

    metric {
      metric_name = "VolumeWriteOps"
      namespace   = "AWS/EBS"
      period      = "60"
      stat        = "Sum"
      dimensions = {}
    }
  }

  metric_query {
    id = "m2"

    metric {
      metric_name = "VolumeReadOps"
      namespace   = "AWS/EBS"
      period      = "60"
      stat        = "Sum"
      dimensions = {}
    }
  }
    lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [metric_query.1.metric.dimensions]
  }
}
```

I have tried various iterations of the `ignore_changes` block and so far have only succeeded if I set the value to `[metric_query]` but that then ignores the whole thing whereas I am trying just to target the `metric_query.metric.dimensions` piece.  Anyone have any clever ideas around addressing this block?

Comment: What TF version and aws provider are you using?

Comment: 0.13.7 for TF and have just bumped aws to latest 3.49.0 but was still getting the error around sets.

Comment: Can you try with newer TF version? I recall such issue before, and I think it was due to old TF version.

Comment: Are you trying to ignore `metric_dimensions` arguments for all blocks, or just the second block?

Comment: For metric Id m1 and m2 but that equates to all dimension blocks as they are defined I guess

Comment: my syntax above was an example of me trying to get the syntax correct so apologies if it made it unclear what the end goal was @MattSchuchard